# Rational between irrationals, irrational between rationals

Tags: calculus

I came across the following question in a textbook:
$$\text{If } f\left(x\right) = \begin{cases} x, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0, & x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases} $$
Show that $f\left(x\right)$ is only continuous at $x=1$.

So I thought: no problem. First prove that it is continuous at $x=0$. Use the proof that between any pair of rationals lies an irrational to show that either side of zero lies immediately an irrational so we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f\left(x\right) =0. $$
I then patted myself on the back for a job well done and set about the 'only' part. Combining the irrational between any rationals with the rational between any irrationals proofs gives me alternating $x$ and 0 values for the function $\Rightarrow$ not continuous anywhere else.

Question one: 
is the above valid?

Question two: 
if so, does my combining of the irrational between rationals and rational between irrationals not suggest that the cardinality of rationals and irrationals is the same as you can set up a correspondence between the countable rationals and the uncountable irrationals?

Comment: "Show that $f(x)$ is only continous at $x=1$ " But then you show it for $x=0$ ?

Comment: For Question one, note that $|f(x)| \le |x|$, this gives continuity at zero. You need to be more explicit about how you handle $x \neq 0$. Your text suggests that you have the correct approach. For Question two, the answer is no. Between any two rationals there are far more irrationals than there are rationals between two irrationals.

Comment: Apparently, it suggests to a lot of people that the rationals and irrationals have the same cardinality; but considering how easy it is to prove that there is no one-one correspondence between the two sets, it's clear that the suggestion is false.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :I would suggest to use convergence of sequences in these types of questions. we can choose a sequence of rationals which will convergence to..